# Building WSTP C++ code with MSVS 2013

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

Has anyone successfully built WSTP code using MSVS 2013 C++?

When I followed the online documentation (based on MSVS 2012) in Mathematica 11.1.1, something seemed to be missing, because when I built, and then tried to run, the sample project 'factor', it did not even ask for MathKernel.exe. (When running the pre-built factor.exe, it was OK, though.) Thanks.

Comment: It was OK with MSVS 2015.